# Name of trunk-like objects

Tags: piece-information, instructions, part-identification

What's the name of the black curved elements in the header/banner of https://www.flickr.com/groups/lego_arboretum/?

The full picture along with some others of the same diorama can be seen here:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/mark-of-falworth/sets/72157638713690815

In addition, does anyone know whether there is an instruction guide for these trees?

Comment: Ah, found the source of the header/banner: https://www.flickr.com/photos/mark-of-falworth/sets/72157638713690815

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the piece you're referring to is [Dinosaur Tail / Neck Middle Section with Pin](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=40378).

Comment: Thanks. Did they use the same pieces for these trees http://www.flickr.com/photos/tiberium_blue/8621407311/in/photostream/? In that case I can't see how it is connected to the 1x1 Round Brick.

Comment: I think they are the same tail pieces, and bits are connected using [Bar 4L (Lightsaber Blade / Wand)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30374)...

Comment: Great! In addition to the `Bar 4L` elements, I see some Reddish Brown tubes/hoses in the link from my previous comment (they seem to be cut in different lengths). Would you happen to know the name/description of this element as well?

Comment: The hoses are probably: [Hose, Rigid 3mm D.](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=528).